# Ubuntu ls doesn't show all the files, but when I "ls filename", it shows up?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell, ls, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using PHP 7.3 to move some files around, in a larger app.
The PHP 7 is running on Ubuntu 20.04.4 in a wsl2 container in Windows 10.

On reading through other questions, it seems this is probably weirdness from windows-subsystem-for-linux, but I need to work out how to rectify it?

Once complete, there should be a group of files and a directory within. Everything works without error, and then I go to the directory and this happens:

```
root@mymachine:/data/temp# ls 4583308_163*                  <---- list glob
4583308_163_master.jpg

4583308_163:
TileGroup0  TileGroup1  4583308_163.xml

root@mymachine:/data/temp# ls 4583308_163                   <---- tab completions
4583308_163/            4583308_163_master.jpg

root@mymachine:/data/temp# ls 4583308_163.jpg               <---- individual filenames show????
4583308_163.jpg
```

So an `ls` glob shows a file that I didn't move and a directory that has been created and files that have just been moved into that directory, *but* there are also 3 other files moved into the top level and they aren't showing.

Tab completions don't show them either, but if I `ls` the filename of the file that is there, I can see it!?

The file is definitely there, and can be seen by other commands if opened directly but globbing fails (`file 4583308_163.jpg` is good, `file 4583308_163.*` gives no such file or directory error)

You'd think after over 25 years of *nix I'd have an answer for this... Anyone have an idea?

I have tried using `bash` and `sh`, and it is the same on both. `find` also can't "find" the files.

Restarting wsl with `wsl --shutdown` doesn't work - I'm not admin and it's a work computer, and I can't get admin. So my thinking is that the only way I can see those files is to restart the computer, which I just did and *I still can't see the files*.

**Update**
When I left on Friday, my machine needed updates, so I shut it down and did the updates as I left work. I turn up today, and it seems to be working fine.

I don't know if it is fixed totally (from the updates?), but I can't reproduce the problem now.

Comment: Are you sure the situation is actually static? The application might be receiving requests from the network, and be actively creating/moving/deleting files within the directory, possibly faster than you (or any human) can follow. Or is this directory a remote SMB or NFS share? That might cause some weirdness related to network communication delays and local caching, if someone or something else is also performing operations on the share.

Comment: how about just plain `ls` (or `ls -a`) would the file show in the list then?

Comment: @steeldriver, but the glob should also expand to `4583308_163.jpg` if that file is there, and if it isn't, that last `ls 4583308_163.jpg` should give an error.

Comment: @ilkkachu ah sorry - not enough coffee to notice the difference in filenames. I said I was confused ;)

Comment: @steeldriver, yep, I don't blame you, I'm also confused about the behaviour there. :)

Comment: Just to confirm -- `/data` is on the WSL2 Ext4 drive and is not a symlink to a Windows drive, right?  Also, I'm not expecting it to reveal anything new, but a `stat 4583308_163.jpg` might be worthwhile.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that, since this appears limited to globbing, that `ls | grep '4583308_163\.jpg'` returns the file, right?

Comment: I think you need to check whether this is contained on an NTFS partition, and whether windows has removed advanced permissions such as `List` or some combination.

Comment: I don't have the machine in front of me, and won't till Wednesday, but I think I can answer some of these questions. @Bib - I don't know, will have to check on Wednesday.  @NotTheDr01ds - /data is located on the ext4 drive, so symlink. Also - I think `ls | grep _file_` doesn't return the file, will have to double check that. That answer also applies to @ikkachu. @telcoM, the program has stopped running, so the environment is definitely static. And it isn't remote.